# Table not found on postresql connection from spring boot 2

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to perform a basic connection between to a local postgresql DB from a very basic SpringBootProject (for training purpose).

```
# configure postgresql
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

So far, I have managed to have it compile and run... but when I am trying to access my DB, I get a "Table "FILMS" not found" error (org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException). When I insert data from a data.sql, I get the inserted movies. But without this initializer, I cannot get data from my db...

> Table "FILMS" not found; SQL statement:
>
> select film0_.code as
> code1_0_, film0_.date_prod as date_pro2_0_, film0_.did as did3_0_,
> film0_.kind as kind4_0_, film0_.title as title5_0_ from films film0_
> [42102-197]
>
> 2018-07-26 12:24:18.151 ERROR 10376 --- [nio-9000-exec-1]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not prepare statement; SQL [select film0_.code as code1_0_,
> film0_.date_prod as date_pro2_0_, film0_.did as did3_0_, film0_.kind
> as kind4_0_, film0_.title as title5_0_ from films film0_]; nested
> exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
> prepare statement] with root cause
>
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "FILMS" non trouvée

Spring boot is in version 2.03 RELEASE; both postgresql connector AND server's ones are 9.4.
I am using spring boot parent starter, as well as data-jpa-starter (with no extra hibernate/jpa depencies defined).

The source code is [here](https://github.com/RogerLapin/pocProm)

My postresql server is up, the database  "db" exists, and its table public."FILMS" is full of data...

Any idea on what I am doing (or undestanding) wrong?

Comment: The error message clearly shows you are using H2, not Postgres, but you added the `postgresql` tag. So which DBMS are you really using? If you expect to be using Postgres, then your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") connects to the wrong database

Comment: Perfect : you pointed out my mistake. I removed h2 db from pom, then got another error... So I fixed the url properties to ".url" instead of "jdbc-url", and there it is! I updated the sources : https://github.com/RogerLapin/pocProm/commit/e7e680c6797dc169e46916cf90497198491b7263. Please consider adding this as an answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

In your application properties file try 
    `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`

It will try to check the table in your db

Comment: The matter was eventually not about the model, but about the way to access it!